# Firebug finds error which does not exist

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

```
<iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed..."></iframe>
```

Firebug - Console tab:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
```

I search entire site (Ctrl+F) and "toString" does not exist.
When I remove iframe - Error disappears.

Comment: Is this error actually affecting the performance of your site? If not, I would ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browser bug that related to the flash player. You can ignore that.

Comment: Are you sure ? I hope so. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Why would a Flash file cause a Javascript error?` Good question.

Comment: The iframe itself is not a flash player in itself, but, an html page. On this page exists html, script and a flash object or player. Any of the scripts on that page could be causing this issue. Not the player itself.

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answers, the bug exists on the page within the iframe. If you're curious as to whats exactly causing the bug... browse to that page within the source and then conduct your search.